request.getParameter method gives null when form data submitted using javascript to servlet, why?
Here is form in JSP
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <form action="FormServlet" method="post" id="contact-form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
        <div class="row gy-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="name-field" class="pb-2">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name-field" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="email-field" class="pb-2">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email-field">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="subject-field" class="pb-2">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject-field">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="message-field" class="pb-2">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" id="message-field"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div><!-- End Contact Form -->

here is Javascript file code included in JSP file
document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

    const form = this; // Get the form
    const formData = new FormData(form); // Create FormData object from the form

    // You can also append other fields if necessary, e.g.:
    // formData.append('customField', 'value'); 

    // Get the action URL of the form (this should be the servlet URL)
    const action = form.action;

    //const action = 'http://localhost:9090/portfolio/FormServlet' 

    // Show loading message or spinner if necessary
    //document.getElementById('responseMessage').textContent = 'Submitting...';

    // Send the form data to the servlet using Fetch API

    fetch(action, {
            method: 'POST', // HTTP method for form submission
            body: formData, // The FormData object

        })
        .then(response => response.ok) // Assuming the servlet returns JSON
        .then(data => {
            // Handle successful response from the servlet
            //document.getElementById('responseMessage').textContent = 'Form submitted successfully!';
            console.log(data); // Process response if necessary
            form.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');

        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle any error that occurs during the fetch
            //document.getElementById('responseMessage').textContent = 'Error submitting form!';
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
});

and here is servlet
package com.pz.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FormServlet
 */
public class FormServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FormServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("firstname");
        System.out.println(name);

        if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
            response.getWriter().println("Name field is required.");
            return;
        }
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("OK");
    }

}


When I remove javascript file from jsp, form date get submitted to servlet and request.getParameter("firstname"); works fine and prints name on console. but when I include javascript request.getParameter("firstname"); prints null on console.

Have you checked in the browser Network developer tool to see the outgoing HTTP request? That will let you see if your JavaScript code is successfully preparing the form content.

Yes pointy in Developer tool, in network tab I see payload like this  =>  firstname: Pravin
email: Xenon@com
subject: TEST
message: EXAMPLE Body and headers like this => Request URL:
http://localhost:9090/portfolio/FormServlet
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
[::1]:9090
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

And when you click your "Submit" button (or however the form is triggered), you're sure there's only one HTTP transaction? (I think that is probably OK, but it's worth checking.)

Hi I got the solution, I compared request headers with and without JavaScript.js file,  then I have made some changes in js file, added this  > const urlEncodedData = new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(); < and > fetch(action, {
method: 'POST',  // HTTP method for form submission
body: urlEncodedData,  // The FormData object
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
}) <in fetch function so now I am able to get data submitted from jsp form to javascript which will be forwarded to servlet. thanks Pointy.

here is the solution
document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default form submission

const form = this;  // Get the form
const formData = new FormData(form);  // Create FormData object from the form

// You can also append other fields if necessary, e.g.:
// formData.append('customField', 'value'); 

// Get the action URL of the form (this should be the servlet URL)
const action = form.action;

const urlEncodedData = new URLSearchParams(formData).toString();


// Show loading message or spinner if necessary
//document.getElementById('responseMessage').textContent = 'Submitting...';

// Send the form data to the servlet using Fetch API

fetch(action, {
    method: 'POST',  // HTTP method for form submission
    body: urlEncodedData,  // The FormData object
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
})
.then(response => response.ok)  // Assuming the servlet returns JSON
.then(data => {
    // Handle successful response from the servlet
    //document.getElementById('responseMessage').textContent = 'Form submitted successfully!';
        console.log(data);  // Process response if necessary
        form.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');

})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle any error that occurs during the fetch
    //document.getElementById('responseMessage').textContent = 'Error submitting form!';
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

});

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
